# Convert GSON to JSON in client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, gson, pojo

is it possible to convert a complex Java object to a JSON String using javascript or jquery?

Comment: GSON is just a Java library for creating JSON.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do here?  i.e. what do you mean by a "Java object"?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(<theObjectYouGotFromYourJavaBackend>)`

Comment: ["Gson (also known as Google Gson) is an open source Java library to serialize and deserialize Java objects to (and from) JSON."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson). So, not sure why you would need to do this in JS if the library does this for you.

Comment: Maybe, if you first show how you pass this Java object to Javascript/JQuery lib and how this JS reads it? After that it is really easy to parse I guess.